# MFC .dll, CString problems, IDA c++ pseudocode, how close is it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, ida

I have some IDA pseudo c++ code and I was wondering how close it was...

The lines:

```
CHAR Filename; // [sp+26Ch] [bp-110h]@1
char v31; // [sp+36Ch] [bp-10h]@1
int v32; // [sp+378h] [bp-4h]@1

GetModuleFileNameA(0, &Filename, 0x100u);
CString__CString(&v31, &Filename);
v32 = 0;
CString::MakeLower(&v31);
if ( CString__Find(&v31, "notepad") != -1 ) 
...
```

As the decompiled .dll uses CString I have assumed that it is a MFC based dll.  I thought, reading the docs that CString would be immediately available.  However, I get the error Error    1   error C2665: 'ATL::CStringT::CStringT' : none of the 17 overloads could convert all the argument types?

I also get similar errors with MakeLower and Find, which according to what I have read are standard CString functions so where am I going wrong?

Also, you are supposed to be able to use the CString class in non mfc based .dll's by using teh #include  header, however, I get the same Error   1   error C2039: 'CString' : is not a member of 'ATL::CStringT' so again how do I use it?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Post the snippet of code that generates C2665, and exact error message (specifically, what are the argument types it complains about). 2. Post the code that generates C2039.

Answer (score 1):

hexrays will produces more C-like code than C++ with objects.
so all 'this' pointers are passed explicitly.

to clear things up you should probably change the type of v31   to CString.

and i think  the compiler will not understand that  CString__CString( <>, FileName)     is the constructor.

so you should change that yourself in:

CString v31(FileName);